# Calibrating a resistive touchscreen for libinput

Tags: yocto, touchscreen

I'm using a [GUI application framework](https://github.com/linux4sam/egt/) (EGT) on an ATMEL/ Microchip SAMA5D4. The framework features

> DRM/KMS and X11 backends.

I've looked at using tslib to calibrate a restive touchscreen for the device but due to EGT limitations it looks like I'm going to have to use libinput for the moment.

Is there a calibration mechanism (equivalent of tslib) available for libinput? I've looked at xlibinput_calibrator & it seems like it could be a solution but I'll have to sort out the dependencies in the Yocto build.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this xlibinput_calibrator looks like it requires X11 & was not an option.

I eventually ended up using a startup script to prevent EGT capturing raw events (deleted /dev/event0 or similiar) from the touchscreen & instead use the calibrated source from ts_input.